# Convert code C# 2008 to code C# 2005?

Tags: c#-2.0

I want convert code C# 2008 to code C# 2005, I did not understand the command C# 2008 to switch to C# 2005, see below is the error code can solve the error command do ? run the code in C# 2008 very good

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = textBox1.Text.Trim();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        // Error in here
        Expression<Func<CustomData, bool>> expr = n => GetCondition(n, str);
        this.gridControl1.DataSource = this.lstCustomData.Where<CustomData>(expr.Compile()).ToList();
    }
    else
        this.gridControl1.DataSource = this.lstCustomData;
    this.gridControl1.RefreshDataSource();
}

public class CustomData
{
    // Error in here
    public int col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
    public string col3 { get; set; }
    public int col4 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've fixed your code formatting, but I left your original sentence as I didn't understand it well enough to improve it. Note that the language versions involved are 3 and 2... 2008 and 2005 are versions of Visual Studio. Now, it's not clear *why* you want to use C# 2, rather than the much-clearer C# 3 code. Could you explain that please? If it's just that you don't understand the C# 3 features here (lambda expressions, extension methods, automatically implemented properties) you'd be better off learning those.

Comment: Another good question is what version of .NET framework do you use, as the language is only of part of the puzzle - if you are using the corresponding .NET 2.0 it misses some types also.

Comment: Well - GetCondition returns something based on the input used to filter the lstCustomData. Figure out how that GetCondition works and you can rewrite it simple enough .... but it begs the question; Is it a requirement that you run C# 2 and cannot upgrade to 3.5?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: The question "Is it a requirement that you run C# 2 and cannot upgrade to 3.5" suggests that there's a C# 3.5; there isn't. There's C# 1, C# 1.2, C# 2, C# 3, C# 4, C# 5 and C# 6. There's .NET 3.5, but that's a different matter. It's worth distinguishing between the version of C# you use and the version of .NET you run against - they can differ significantly.

Comment: As another aside, this code appears to be using expression trees instead of delegates for no reason whatsoever...

Comment: Yes, you don't need to create expression tree and compile it there - it is the same if you just use Func. The code with expressions will be extremely ugly to be translated to older versions of C# even if you use newer .NET framework and you have Expression classes, but lambdas are kind of easy to translate...

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well C# 2.0 didn't have lambdas and expressions. Lambdas have one pretty cool feature - they can capture local variables and use them. If you cannot use them directly you need to emulate their behavior. How the C# 3.0 compiler handles the lambdas actually?

It creates a Closure class with fields for all the data to be captured, create an instance of this class where the lambda is defined and puts all the data to the fields. It also creates a method to the class with the same signature as the lambda and uses this method instead.

This technique should solve your problem, but will make your code a bit more complex. You will need to create a private class like this:

```
private class WhereLambda
{
    private string str;
    public WhereLambda(string str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public bool IsTrue(CustomData data)
    {
         return GetCondition(data, this.str);
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
WhereLambda lambda = new WhereLambda(str);
this.gridControl1.DataSource = this.lstCustomData.Where<CustomData>(lambda.IsTrue).ToList();
```

Comment: I have some memories how C# used to be :)

Comment: How this code convert ? it use automatic properties
[code]
public class CustomData
{
    // Error in here
    public int col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
    public string col3 { get; set; }
    public int col4 { get; set; }
}
[/code]

Comment: What kind of error do you get? I don't remember well when the auto-implemented properties arrived - they could be missing in C# 2.0, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Automatic properties convert like this: private string _col1; public string col1 { get { return this._col1; } set { this._col1 = value; } }

Comment: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DBSearch.CustomData>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' ...
this.gridControl1.DataSource = this.lstCustomData.Where<CustomData>(lambda.IsTrue).ToList();
Error 2 Cannot access a nonstatic member of outer type 'DBSearch.Form1' via nested type 'DBSearch.Form1.WhereLambda' ...
return GetCondition(data, this.str);